# Get affected rows PostgreSQL C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, .net-core

Previously I had method which depending on whether I have version or not would either increment it or insert new column:

```
public void Increment(int id, long version)
    {
        if (version == 0)
        {
            _db.ExecuteNonQuery($@"
                INSERT INTO table (id, version)
                VALUES (:id, 0)
                ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
            ", _db.CreateParameter("id", id));
        }

        var affectedRows = _db.ExecuteNonQuery($@"
            UPDATE table
            SET version = version + 1
            WHERE id = :id AND version = :preVersion;
            ",
            _db.CreateParameter("id", id),
            _db.CreateParameter("version", preVersion));

        if (affectedRows != 1)
            throw new Exception("None Updated");
    }
```

now I will not longer have version passed to me, so I am trying to use IF EXISTS statement to figure out whether I should insert or update. However, the problem is that the way I write my sql it doesn't return affected rows count and I am not sure how to change it. Currently it looks something like this:

```
public void Increment(int id)
    {
        var affectedRows = _db.ExecuteNonQuery($@"
        DO
        $do$
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id = {id}) THEN
                UPDATE table
                SET version = version + 1, updated = '{DateTime.Now}'
                WHERE id = {id} AND (updated IS NULL);
            ELSE 
                INSERT INTO table (id, version, updated)
                VALUES ({id}, 0, '{DateTime.Now}');
            END IF;
        END
        $do$");

        if (affectedRows != 1)
            throw new Exception($"None updated");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `id` is either a primary key or that it has an unique constraint then use your second example with this query, based on yours. It tries to insert, if that fails because `id` already exists then update but only if `updated is null`. I guess that this is exactly your logic but reordered and reworded in plain SQL.

```sql
INSERT INTO the_table (id, version, updated) VALUES ({id}, 0, current_timestamp)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE 
SET version = version + 1, updated = current_timestamp WHERE updated IS NULL;
```

I have substituted `{DateTime.Now}` with SQL-standard `current_timestamp`, hopefully for better readability.